# How to fix height problem with listview in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, height

I spend so much time about this ... Can somebody help me to solve this ?
My goal is to make a list of cards (frames), each card having two labels and a (short) list of items.

To make things more readable, I chose to make a custom component with the frame and its contend.
If I make a list of frames, each frames having only the labels, every things looks good (first image). The height of the frames is only the needed height, no more.
BUT ... when I add the second level of listview in the frames, all those lists waste a lot of empty height after their items (second image) !!! And I can't get rid of this wasted space ... Grrrr ...

[image][image]

I publish you only the code of the custom component (with the second level of listview):

```
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame BorderColor="Gray"
               CornerRadius="5"
               Padding="8">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Data.TaskHeading, Source={x:Reference this}}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Data.PeopleHeading, Source={x:Reference this}}"/>
                
                <BoxView Color="Gray"
                         HeightRequest="2"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Tasks, Source={x:Reference this}}" BackgroundColor="Pink" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding mark}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding description}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

I try to add VerticalAlign="Start" everywhere but it doesn't help.
The use of HasUnevenRows="True" has no influence on this problem.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: nested listviews are almost always a horrible, horrible idea.  If you really need this, consider using ListView grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it using [BindableLayouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).

The following code is very similar to what you need. I wrote a basic models, you can always implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if you need it.

**Model/ViewModel:**

```
public class CardModel
{
    public string TaskHeading { get; set; }
    public string PeopleHeading { get; set; }

    public CardItemModel[] Items { get; set; }

    public class CardItemModel
    {
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}

public class CardsPageViewModel
{
    public CardModel[] Tasks { get; set; }

    public CardsPageViewModel()
    {
        Tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i =>
            new CardModel
            {
                TaskHeading = $"TaskHeading {i}",
                PeopleHeading = $"People Heading {i}",
                Items = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(j =>
                    new CardModel.CardItemModel
                    {
                        Mark = $"Mark {j}",
                        Description = $"Description {j}"
                    }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
...
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks, Mode=OneWay}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TaskHeading, Mode=OneWay}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PeopleHeading, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" BackgroundColor="LightPink">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Mark, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
...
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT**: I forgot to add the ViewBox separator and Frame CornerRadius and BorderColor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It is so clear and detailled. I was not expecting such a complete reponse. I'm really impressed. I don't knew the BindableLayout. It seems really interesting. I will look at this very closely. Thanks again for this.